# TikZ legend changes the line legend into a rectangle legend

Tags: matlab, matlab2tikz

I am using TikZ to insert MATLAB figures but the problem is that I have two legends one is a line and the other is a rectangle. When I insert it, both look like a rectangle. How should I correct it ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It would also be helpful to post the file generated by `matlab2tikz`. Usually editing the contents in that file would solve the problem.

Comment: \begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
area legend,
scale only axis,
xmin=-0.122133156889097,
xmax=0.157640000010714,
xlabel={Sample Value},
ymin=-0.0996388680321313,
ymax=18.544428928578,
ylabel={Probability Density/Histogram},
title={Distribution Fitting},
legend style={at={(0.593948267447536,0.733640081799591)},anchor=south west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left},
scaled x ticks = false, 
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=2}
]

Answer (score 1):

Your description is minimal, but I think I had the same problem. Please try opening the matlab2tikz.m file, find the line

```
sprintf(['\\addplot [',opts,']\n'])];
```

within `function str = plotLine2d(m2t, opts, data)`, and change it to

```
sprintf(['\\addplot [line legend,',opts,']\n'])];
```

It is not a very elegant solution, but it worked for me.

Regards,
Björn